# Reselecting text in content editable div after re-rendering-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

I am trying to implement a simple text editor in React. I have a content editable div, and a button. What I want to achieve is to

- Select text in the content editable div
- When I press the button , which is outside the content editable div, to make the text bold
- Re-render the component to capture the inner html of the content editable div to display the content as preview under the editor
- Preserve the selection **after** the re-render, for any possible further edits on the selected text, for example, make it italic in addition for being bold.

The problem I am facing is that, when I make the selected text bold, by inserting a span with class `text-bold` with the selected text as its content in place of the selected text, I need to re-render the component to capture the new html code inside the content editable div, to display the content of the editor as preview under the editor (the same as it happens here on StackOverflow). However, when the component re-renders, I cannot restore the selection. I tried to use `useEffect` to implement this, but it didn't work.

So, my question is: how can restore the selection after I re-render the component?

This is the full code (here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-snowflake-gqbi1?file=/src/App.js:0-2030) code)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState("<p>Hello World!</p>");
  const [selectionRange, setSelectionRange] = useState(null);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (selectionRange) {
  //     // Restore selection
  //     let sel = window.getSelection();
  //     sel.removeAllRanges();
  //     sel.addRange(selectionRange);
  //     console.log(sel.toString());
  //   }
  // }, [htmlContent, selectionRange]);

  const storeSelectionRange = () => {
    if (window.getSelection().toString().length) {
      const sel = window.getSelection();
      const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      setSelectionRange(range);
    }
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    if (selectionRange) {
      // Restore selection
      let sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(selectionRange);

      // Create a new html element with the selected text as its content
      const newNode = document.createElement("span");
      newNode.className = "text-bold";
      const newContent = document.createTextNode(sel.toString());
      newNode.appendChild(newContent);

      // Re-select the text to be replace by the newly created element
      let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(newNode);
      // setSelectionRange(range);

      // Update the html inside the content editable div with class "editor__content"
      const newHtml = document.querySelector(".content").innerHTML;
      setHtmlContent(newHtml);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="editor">
        <div
          className="content"
          contentEditable="true"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }}
          onBlur={storeSelectionRange}
        ></div>
        <button className="btn" onClick={onClick}>
          Bold
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="selected-text">{htmlContent}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You could use a useRef hook to store the selectionRange. It persists through rerenders, but does not trigger a render when changed. Then you could use useEffect with htmlContent as dependency.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work. I suspect that the range of selection changes when I insert the span, and I need to modify the selection, but not sure how to test that